# Multiple Strpos checks

Tags: php

Would there be anyway to merge the below queries into a single function? As it stands only the second Strpos function works. If i remove the second one then the first one will work. I need to run both as I have to check for 2 separate strings.

```
$check1 = QueryWhoisServer($whoisserver, $domain);
if(strpos($check1,"No match for") !== FALSE){

return "Result Example";
}
$check2 = QueryWhoisServer($whoisserver, $domain);
if(strpos($check2,"No Data Found") !== FALSE){

return "Result 2 example";
}
else {
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you should keep the output of your whois query.

```
$response = QueryWhoisServer($whoisserver, $domain);
```

Then, you can run multiple searches:

```
if (false !== strpos($response, 'No match for')) {
  // ...
} elseif (false !== strpos($response, 'No Data Found')) {
  // ...
} else {
  // ...
}
```